# Prove or disprove $\operatorname{Spin}(2n) \supset U(1) \times SU(n)$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Question: Let us prove
$$\operatorname{Spin}(2n) \supset U(1) \times SU(n)?$$
or disprove it, thus
$$\operatorname{Spin}(2n) \not\supset U(1) \times SU(n)?$$

I suggest:

- We can prove this is true  for $n=1,2,$.
- We can disprove this for $n \geq 3$.
- We can disprove this for $n=5$.

Are there general principle behind for generic $n$??

For
$$n=3,  \quad Spin(6)=SU(4) \supset U(1) \times SU(3) $$

For
$$n=4,  \quad Spin(8)  \supset U(1) \times SU(4)? $$
may not be true.
For
$$n=5,   \quad  Spin(10)  \supset U(1) \times SU(5) ?$$
may not be true

Comment: Did you do a dimension count?

Comment: [Slansky Table 14](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  Due diligence first.

Comment: Thanks, but it says Lie algebra but NOT Lie group. It says the Lie algebra  $$su(10) \supset su(5) \times u(1).$$ - but I am not sure it is correct for the group structure
$$SO(10) \supset SU(5) \times  U(1)???$$  Maybe it is only for Lie algebra

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Furthermore, $Spin(10)$  is not a subgroup of $SO(10)$, but a quotient group so 
$$Spin(10) \not\supset   SO(10)$$
thus even if $SO(10) \supset SU(5)  \times U(1)$ is true, it does not prove that
$$Spin(10) \supset SU(5)  \times U(1)???$$
Thank you!

Comment: For 
$$n=1,  Spin(2)=U(1) \supset U(1) \times SU(1)= U(1)$$

Comment: For 
$$n=2,  Spin(4)=SU(2) \times SU(2) \supset U(1) \times SU(2) $$

Comment: For 
$$n=3,  Spin(6)=SU(4) \supset U(1) \times SU(3) $$

Comment: For 
$$n=4,  Spin(8)  \supset U(1) \times SU(4) ??$$
may not be true

Comment: For 
$$n=5,  Spin(10)  \supset U(1) \times SU(5) ??$$
may not be true

Comment: Your $n=3$ case is wrong.  There is no embedding of $SU(3)\times U(1)$ into $SU(4)$.  There is, however, an embedding of $U(3)$, which is triple covered by $SU(3)\times U(1)$.

Comment: @Jason DeVito, I think I am correct. Can we choose U(1) Lie algebra generator as diag(1,1,1,-3) in SU(4), so SU(3) is include the 3 by 3 matrix of SU(4), and U(1) is still in SU(4), satisfying determinant of such U(1) is still 1 so in SU(4)?

Comment: Are you working in the Lie algebra or the Lie group?  I agree that there is a copy of $\mathfrak{su}(3)\oplus \mathfrak{u}(1)$ in $\mathfrak{su}(4)$.  In the group, there is no copy of $U(1)$ which lives just in the bottom right coordinate.  (because the determinant would not be $1$)

Comment: How is this ? consider the U(1) generated by $$exp(i \theta \; diag(1,1,1,-3))$$ in SU(4) with $\theta in [0, 2 \pi)$ up to some factor. This generator has $$\det exp(i \theta \;  diag(1,1,1,-3))=exp(i \theta \;  tr[diag(1,1,1,-3)])=1$$
Something like this?